# Android: Display custom dialog in center of the container

Tags: android, android-dialog

How to display custom dialog as a center of the container?

```
Dialog customdialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar); 
Window window = customdialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

`R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar` - is used to remove border for cutomdialog. Once i used this line the dialog will appear at the topleft corner of the tablet?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: to remove border  create custom background and add this to style <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Change the fill_parent to wrap_content.I hope this will be the issue the dialog appear at the corner of the activity.It takes the space of whole layout.So changing this may help you to get what you realy wanted.

```
Window window = customdialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Use above code after dialog.show() statement

Comment: Accepting the answer and upvoting it will help us both to improve the reputation So please do the same with this ans @Kamal So happy to help you out.:-)

Comment: But i want without giving window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); is it possible

Comment: Tried  window.setDimAmount(0.5f); but it is not working. Then took Root layout to main layout and set width and height to fill parent , background semi transparent but layout coming in top.

Answer (score 14):

I added this to the dialog's custom style and it worked fine.

```
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
```

My dialog's width and height are set to wrap_content. The style's parent is

parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"

Comment: Indeed I did as suggested by Sreedev but I couldn't get my dialog at the center. Adding this parameter in my style solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for this piece of code:

```
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        //This makes the dialog take up the full width
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Where dialog, is the dialog object to be shown. Inside of the layout of the dialog you can define the view of the layout as you wish: centered or not.

Comment: Do NOT copy LayoutParams, it breaks border rendering. Use lp = window.getAttributes();

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and the problem solved

```
Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```