# How to align custom dialog centre in android ?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am working on the application where i wanted to display the dialog to be screen size. So i used code below.I got the solution through here [Alert message is not displaying in alert dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432184/alert-message-is-not-displaying-in-alert-dialog-box)

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("DM2");
    title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    title.setTextSize(20);


    TextView text = new TextView(this);  
    text.setText("Hello This text");  
    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    text.setTextSize(20);        
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //Creates a linearlayout layout and sets it with initial params
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ll.addView(text); 
    builder.setCustomTitle(title);
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }); 

    Dialog d = builder.setView(ll).create();
    //Fills up the entire Screen
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    d.show();
    d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

But I want dialog to be appeared in center aligned. Now it is display in top of the window. 
I tried with lp.garvity = Gravity.center, but didn't work.
and If the device orientation changes, i need to press ok button more time to close the dialog. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance
Pushpa

Comment: did you try writing     d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  before  d.show(); ?

Comment: I tried but it will not display the alert box to window size

Answer (score 9):

I'm little late, but better late then never :-)
you can use the code below: (I saw also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412653/1918752))

```
dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_photo_dialog);

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//The below code is EXTRA - to dim the parent view by 70%
LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.7f;
lp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
//Show the dialog
dialog.show();
```

Hope I helped...

Comment: Nice answer, I use `window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` instead of 'window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT)',it works fine,thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Comment: @pushpa: hey try gravity center by setting height to wrap_content

Comment: @unreachable: I tried this will display the dialog in center, I have view with 3 buttons in background and want to hide that view. height wrap content will not hide the background view.

Comment: @pushpa: hey in that case you can make the background of your popup not transparent you can use getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);

Answer (score 2):

Try to use android:layout_gravity="center" instead of android:gravity="center"... It may be helpful for you..

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or

you can try this..

```
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name=".Splash">
    </activity>
```

> Write full xml code and make simple Activty and add one attribute  in
>   AndroidManifest.xml, when you registering your Activity into
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: For custom dialog you can do one thing, Make your whole screen like Activity screen, and add the Theme:@dialog in AndroidManifest.xml.. that your whole content will display as a dialog.

Comment: I had the mAlertDialog?.window?.setLayout stretched to match parent but i wanted to centre the AlertDialog itself in the screen. using layout_gravity instead of gravity worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** :- This is for "**custom layout**"... :)

I was struggling with the same, and after struggling for hours i came to this result

Earlier i was creating the  dilaoge like this : -

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PopupforeditActivity.this);
```

After adding style "No titleBar" it started fetching the layout the way I had created.

For this you have to create the layout with params "fillParent"
and create the dialoge like this

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PopupforeditActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_billing_cart);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

The above is coding part

You in `Layout` part
put your whole layout in `RelativeLayout`

and give your layout property `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Ex:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >


<!--Your Layout-->

  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrlView_FormHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And if you don't want to miss "title" You can have that in your custom layout as TextView ..

Hope it will help..
As it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this style to show dialogs in centre android

```
<style name="CustomDialogue" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth" type="dimen">600dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin" type="dimen">8dp</item>
</style>
```

- I used android:layout_gravity to show dialog in centre.
- minWidth is set because otherwise dialog look narrower.
- layout_margin is set so there is enough margin around dialog in smaller screens.

### Before android:layout_gravity="center"

[image: Before]

### After android:layout_gravity="center"

[image: After]