# How to set gravity of WindowFeature supported Activity android

Tags: android, dialog

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity
 {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    }
}
```

when start activity ,it act as dialog .Here problem is the dialog window display at top , but I want it display in center.

Comment: Please check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412192/android-display-custom-dialog-in-center-of-the-container)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to show dialog anywhere with the help of `gravity`

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```